# How to fix RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursionerror

Here's the question:

**07. Define a function named import_zip_codes_json() which imports the zip_codes.json as a list in working directory.**

Here's the code:

```
import json
with open('zip_codes.json') as list:
  zip_codes_json = json.load(list)
```

(The 'def' line is defined by teacher, and what I've wrote is the below part.)

```
def import_zip_codes_json() -> list:

    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
    return zip_codes_json

type(zip_codes_json)
```

I got 'list' for my return, and it's right. But after running all the codes, I've got RecursionError.

```
ERROR: test_07_import_zip_codes_json (__main__.TestMidterm)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-524-ba9f8f20ec9d>", line 48, in test_07_import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  File "<ipython-input-516-0c2ae51a67d5>", line 10, in import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  File "<ipython-input-516-0c2ae51a67d5>", line 10, in import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  File "<ipython-input-516-0c2ae51a67d5>", line 10, in import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  [Previous line repeated 941 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I've searched on Google for solutions, and I've tried to use sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)
```

but I still got RecursionError

```
ERROR: test_07_import_zip_codes_json (__main__.TestMidterm)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-562-ba9f8f20ec9d>", line 48, in test_07_import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  File "<ipython-input-554-0c2ae51a67d5>", line 10, in import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  File "<ipython-input-554-0c2ae51a67d5>", line 10, in import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  File "<ipython-input-554-0c2ae51a67d5>", line 10, in import_zip_codes_json
    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
  [Previous line repeated 19941 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why does your function `import_countries_json()` call itself? Also what is `import_zip_codes_json()` that you have in your full error traceback?

Comment: You need the break condition.

Comment: I see you have updated the code in your question to match the full error traceback. So why does your function `import_zip_codes_json()` call itself? What does that have to do with the snippet above that with the `json.load(list)` in it? Why does question `07` state: `"imports the zip_codes.json"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def import_zip_codes_json() -> list:

    zip_codes_json = import_zip_codes_json()
    return zip_codes_json
```

The first thing `import_zip_codes_json()` does is call itself, which then calls itself, which then calls itself.... forever.  Or until the stack blows up and you get the error.

Why are you doing this?

Comment: @GinoMempin the answer does end with a question, but the text below the code definitely identifies the issue that the OP is asking about.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado The question was "*How can I fix this?*" While it identifies why the recursion error is happening, can't provide a fix without understanding why the OP defined the function like this.... which should be a comment.